# to_categorical() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nb_classes' - tflearn

Tags: typeerror, tflearn

I am trying to run example from https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/bidirectional_lstm.py on jupyter notebook. Since I am new on Tflearn, Jupyter and DNN I could not debug what is the error and how to resolve it. The error look like:

```
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fa67bb48a391> in <module>()
     38 testX = pad_sequences(testX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
     39 # Converting labels to binary vectors
---> 40 trainY = to_categorical(trainY)
     41 testY = to_categorical(testY)
     42 

TypeError: to_categorical() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nb_classes'`
```

Also I could not understand how it is loading the dataset. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like this commit broke it. https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/923

Comment: Did you find the answer useful? If yes, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the latest *stable* version of TFLearn (0.3.2 at the time of writing), installed with `pip`, the argument `nb_classes` is necessary:

```python
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical
from tflearn.datasets import imdb
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path = 'imdb.pkl', n_words = 10000, valid_portion = 0.1)
trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test

trainY[0:5]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

# this gives error:
trainY = to_categorical(trainY)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4a293ba390bc> in <module>()
----> 1 trainY = to_categorical(trainY) #, nb_classes=2)

TypeError: to_categorical() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Essentially, this is the same error message with the one you get, despite the different wording; including `nb_classes=2` resolves it:

```python
trainY = to_categorical(y=trainY, nb_classes=2) 
trainY[0:5]
# array([[ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  0.]])
```

So, what I suggest is:

- Uninstall your current TFLearn
- Install the latest stable version with `pip install tflearn`
- Include the argument `nb_classes=2` in `to_categorical`

Of course, simply updating your code with `nb_classes=2` might work, but it also might not - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001784/tflearn-to-categorical-type-error) and my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter thr same issue.

It looks like the tflearn version is too low and only in the newer version the `nb_classes` argument is no longer required.

You can either try update to the newest version of it. (Not from `pip install tflearn`. Until now--`2017/10/25`--it's not new enough.)
`pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git`

Or you can just add the extra argument, which is a integer indicating the total number of classes, which may vary according to your dataset used.