# tflearn to_categorical type error

Tags: typeerror, tflearn

I keep getting a `typeError` when I try to use `to_categorical` from `tflearn`. The output error is:`

```python
 trainY = to_categorical(y = trainY, nb_classes=2)
  File "C:\Users\saleh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_utils.py", line 46, in to_categorical
    return (y[:, None] == np.unique(y)).astype(np.float32)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

This is the reproducible code that I am trying to run:

```python
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

#IMDB dataset loading
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path = 'imdb.pkl', n_words = 10000, valid_portion = 0.1)
trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test

#converting labels to binary vectors
trainY = to_categorical(y = trainY, nb_classes=2)  # **This is where I get the error**
testY = to_categorical(y = testY, nb_classes=2)
```

Comment: Since it is actually *not* run, the code after the line causing the error is actually irrelevant for the issue. I have edited the post and removed that part for clarity & ease of reading.

Comment: Didn't you find the (updated) answer useful? If yes, kindly accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your error:

```python
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path = 'imdb.pkl', n_words = 10000, valid_portion = 0.1)
trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test

trainY[0:5]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

trainY = to_categorical(y = trainY, nb_classes=2) 
trainY[0:5]
# array([[ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  0.]])
```

System configuration:

- Python 2.7.12
- Tensorflow 1.3.0
- TFLearn 0.3.2
- Ubuntu 16.04

**UPDATE**: It seems that some recent TFLearn commit has broken `to_categorical` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900404/to-categorical-missing-1-required-positional-argument-nb-classes-tflearn) and [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/945). I suggest to uninstall your current version and install the latest **stable** one with `pip install tflearn` (this is actually what I have done myself above).